# fatal authentication failed - password is not shown

Tags: github, github-for-windows

actually, This is my first time trying to approach Github. (via windows)
I have username, password, and public key.
Im trying to

> push origin master

I've typed my username,

and then he asked me for my password: when I type the password in the command prompt, its not doing anything. nothing shown.
and if I try to type the password even if its not shown, I get an error:

fatal: Authontivation failed for ....

any idea why ?

Comment: Authentication failed means that the remote (Github) has said that the username/password combination you've entered don't match. It deliberately does not show you the password that you have entered.

Comment: I still cant connect push.   any ideas what the problem can be ?

Answer (score 0):

```
git commit -m "Initial commit."
```

and it all worked fine